# Removing a directory from .gitignore so git starts to track changes in it

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory `doc` that was in .gitignore. I decided git should track changes in it. But after removing `doc` entry from .gitignore, git didn't automatically start tracking the directory.

**How can I force git to watch for changes in that directory?**

My second concern is, while looking for an answer to above question I found this thread: [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring) and performed these operations:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

I understand that it was wrong move; the above thread discussed totally opposite situation. **Did I ruined something rather badly?**

All this is done on a private, semi-serious project.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think this is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126292/git-trouble-un-ignoring-previously-ignored-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git doesn't track directories at all, rather it tracks (file) content. It may be that you have other conditions in the .gitignore, particulalrly a `!dir` which then, as an optimisation in recent versions, no longer reads further gitignore files in any lower directories.

The gitignore capability is a powerful tool, but has traps for the unwary.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. In my case I had `projects` folder was ignored initially. I removed `projects/` entry which was there in `.gitignore` file. removing that entry didn't help at all.

My solution

1. run `git status --ignored` will give you all ignored files/paths.
2. run `git add -f <file>` where `<file>` could be a file name OR a path that you want to track back. So I had to run `git add -f projects/` and

immediately everything under `projects` folder appeared as changed files.

Answer (score 1):

I removed doc/ folder from project_name/.gitignore file. But there is global config file in user home directory, ~/.gitignore.

And I forgot that I entered doc/ in that file too. So, after erasing doc/ from .gitignore in home directory, everything went smooth.

Comment: You can check what untracked files are hitting your exclude patterns with [`git ls-files -io --exclude-standard`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html), for tracked files it'd be `-ic` not `-io`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem, deleted a folder from the project .gitignore file and git was still ignoring it. The global file did not contain the folder either, but when I looked in .gitconfig I saw this line:

`excludesfile = c://www/.gitignore_global`

This was the file that still had my folder listed, removing the file solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another .gitignore file in any subdirectory, Git will also consider it.